# Delphi - How to access a form from a childwindow in a mdi-application

Tags: delphi, mdi

I have an MDI programm with a child window which contains a TMemo and a button, there is also another Form1 in the application.
Clicking the button:

> ```
> Unit1.Form1.Parent:=Form1;
> Unit1.Form1.Show;
> ```

On Form1 is also a button:

> ```
> ????.(FindComponent('dataMm') as TMemo).lines.append('hallo child');
> ```

My question is: what is the right syntax to replace the ???? to access the TMemo on the childform.

PS.: the TMainForm has the following procedure:

> ```
> Procedure TMainForm.CreateMDIChild(const Name: string);
> var
>   Child: TMDIChild;
> begin
>   Child := TMDIChild.Create(Application);
>   MyChild:=Child;
> end;
> ```

where MyChild is declared in the public section as

> var MyChild: TForm;

Thanks for your time and attention
Regards

Comment: What happens if multiple instances of the child for yare created?

Comment: Thank you for trying to make a good question. However, the structure is not really clear. Please edit and list relevant units and their respective content. Do you have 2 forms named `Form1` (you say: *there is also **another Form1***)? Why don't you change one's name? I don't understand why you use `FindComponent`. You can refer to the memo directly with `FormName.MemoName` if the memo is created at design time. And you can refer to other units by their name. So, please clarify. And why do you declare `var MyChild: TForm;` if the actual type is `TMDIChild`?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this answer, you have not yet responded to my comment where I requested some clarifications, but I believe I understand your problem.

So here is the essens of the main form:

```
unit UMain;

uses
  ..., UChild, ...
    
type
  TMDIMainForm = class(TForm)
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    CreateChild1: TMenuItem;
    ShowForm11: TMenuItem;
    ...
  public
    MyChild: TMDIChild;
```

As you usually have many instances of a child form, you need to use a list or array instead of the `MyChild` variable, but this is what you had defined.

And the implementation of those menu items, as well as the `CreateMDIChild` method:

```
procedure TMDIMainForm.CreateChild1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateMDIChild('TheOneAndOnly');
end;

procedure TMDIMainForm.ShowForm11Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.Show;
end;

procedure TMDIMainForm.CreateMDIChild(const name: string);
//var
//  Child: TMDIChild;  no need for this temporary variable
begin
  MyChild := TMDIChild.Create(Application);
  MyChild.Parent := self;
  MyChild.Visible := True;
//  MyChild:=Child;
end;
```

The `TMDIChild` class is as simple as:

```
unit UChild;

type
  TMDIChild = class(TForm)
    dataMm: TMemo;
  end;
```

as it only holds the memo (for the purpose of this discussion).

Finally the `TForm1` class:

```
unit UForm1;

interface
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

implementation

uses UMain, UChild;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MDIMainForm.MyChild.dataMm.Lines.Add('hello child!')
end;
```

I guess we have now arrived to your actual question, how to address the memo in the `MyChild` form.

So, note that you need to add the `uses UMain, UChild;` clause to refer to those units. This `uses` clause must be in the `implementation` part. If it would be in the `interface`part, it would create a circular reference, which is forbidden.

Now you can refer to the memo in the child form which has it's reference in the main form.

---

**Edit**

After you clarified in a comment: (*"Actually the Button to make visible the Form1 is on the child, and this can happen on any child. Than on Form1 a button activates : `dataMm.Lines.Add('hello child!')`. I need a reference or connection to this currently active child"*, you can do as follows:

Add to the `TForm1` type, a new private field to hold the `MDIChild` reference, and a new method, in which you can pass the reference of the calling `MDIChild`, e.g.

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
...
private
  CurrentMDIChild: TMDIChild;
public
  procedure DoActivate(Sender: TMDIChild);
```

The implementation of `DoActivate()` becomes:

```
procedure TForm1.DoActivate(Sender: TMDIChild);
begin
  if (Sender is TMDIChild) then
  begin
    CurrentMDIChild := Sender;
    Show;
  end;
end;
```

The `TMDIChild.Button1Click` becomes e.g.

```
procedure TMDIChild.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.DoActivate(self); 
end;
```

Comment: Actually the Button to make visible the Form1 is on the child, and this can happen on any child. Than on Form1 a button activivates : dataMm.Lines.Add('hello child!'). I need a reference or connection to this currently active child. Sorry for my english and thanks for your help.